# Error .filter is not a function in chrome console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

```
    import {useMemo} from "react";

export const useSortedPosts = (posts, sort) => {
    return useMemo(() => {
        if (sort) {
            return [...posts].sort((a, b) => a[sort].localeCompare(b[sort]))
        }
        return posts;
    }, [sort, posts]);
}

export const usePosts = (posts, sort, query) => {
    const sortedPosts = useSortedPosts(posts, sort);

    return useMemo(() => {
        return sortedPosts.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()))
    }, [query, sortedPosts]);
}
```

there are no errors in webstorm, but error in chrome console: [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciedf.png),[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aemum.png)

Comment: Can you debug and see what the value of `sortedPosts` is before calling `sortedPosts.filter` ? Alternatively you can put a `console.log("sortedPosts", sortedPosts)` before the `sortedPosts.filter`  line. For some reason the sortedPosts is not an array

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your sortedPosts. You should check existing of sortedPosts then create a map for it.

```
return useMemo(() => {
        return sortedPosts ? sortedPosts.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) : null
    }, [query, sortedPosts]);
```

Comment: same way, error sortedPosts.filter is not a function

Comment: why you use useMemo for your sortedPost?